# Take ownership of parameter by rvalue-reference

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, rvalue-reference

I want to make clear that the constructor of my class `A` will take ownership of the passed `Data` parameter. The obvious thing to do is take a `unique_ptr` by value:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::unique_ptr<Data> data) : _data(std::move(data)) { }

    std::unique_ptr<Data> _data;
};
```

However, for my use-case, there is no reason why `Data` should be a pointer, since a value type would suffice. The only remaining option that I could think of to make really clear that `Data` will be owned by `A` is pass by rvalue-reference:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(Data&& data) : _data(std::move(data)) { }

    Data _data;
};
```

Is this a valid way to signal ownership or are there better options to do this without using `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Why does the ctor take ownership?

Comment: I'd make the constructor explicit

Comment: @IvanRubinson For mutliple reasons, such as Dependency Injection.

Comment: well, you answered you own question, yes, move ctor and rvalues in general is the way to go :)

Comment: @sfk92fksdf Ok, thanks! Just wanted to make sure, since I have actually never seen rvalues being used this way...

Comment: Is `Data` copyable ?

Comment: @Jarod42 What consequences would either option have?

Comment: If it is not copyable as `std::unique_ptr`, you may take it by value instead of rvalue reference.

Comment: So this would have the advantage that move does not have to be called explicitly but Data would still be moved. Or am I missing something else?

Comment: @angelag No, if `Data` is non-copyable it just means you may take it by-value and there is no danger the caller might make a copy by accident.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think it is a valid way.

In the case of `unique_ptr`, it is non-copyable, so there is no danger of someone accidentally making a copy when they didn't intend to so both pass-by-value and pass-by-rvalue-reference signify taking ownership.

In the case of `Data`, pass-by-rvalue-reference documents that you are taking ownership and there is no danger of the caller accidentally making a copy when they didn't intend to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a valid way. You can also pass it by value:

```
class A {
    A(Data data) : _data(std::move(data)) { }
};
Data data;
A a(std::move(data));
```

Comment: Of course this is also an option. However, it doesn't enforce to move the object and therefore unnecessary copies could be made.

Comment: @angelag In this case, I think pass-by-value might be a better option. If you want `Data` always has only ONE owner, then you should make it non-copyable, and pass `Data` by value works as what you did with `unique_ptr`. Otherwise, i.e. `Data` is copyable, pass-by-value gives the client two choices: copy it or 'move' it. It's more flexible, and sometimes the client might want to keep a copy of `Data` after passing it to `A`'s constructor.